# Не обновляется вся строка в PostgreSQL через Hibernate + JSON

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot

PUT-запросом передаётся 1 объект JSON для обновления всей строки, которая уже есть в БД PostgreSQL, на новую с обновленными данными. Появляется ошибка:

`org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long com.av.model.CnflEmp.rowId] by reflection for persistent property [com.av.model.CnflEmp#rowId]` +

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.av.model.CnflEmp.rowId to com.av.model.CnflEm`

Интересно то, что при использовании RESTEasy такой ошибки не было и строка в БД обновлялась! Все GET запросы работают корректно. Частично обновлять столбцы нельзя.

**Использую:**

Spring-Boot (2.7.0.),
Hibernate (5.6.5.Final),
PostgreSQL (42.3.5),
Postman

*Классы и поля в БД (ошибка на 80 строке):*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

День мучений, а надо было всего лишь удалить в pom.xml зависимость **spring-boot-devtools**